# Is it possible to send - consistently across channels - a hidden value in a CardAction while displaying something else?

Tags: .net, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Back to the old PostBack/ImBack button type questions.

I've seen queries looking for ways to send a message to the bot without displaying anything to the user. But I'm looking for a consistent way to achieve the button 'holy grail' of:

1. Display text - e.g. 'select'
2. Message that then shows up in the chat feed from user to bot - e.g. 'Ford Mondeo'
3. Actual value that gets sent to bot - e.g. '03 D 27913'

PostBack is the recommended choice for being able to send a value to the bot without showing it to the user. However, I actually *want* to show something to the user, to indicate that something is happening. If you click on a button and nothing happens for a second or two, users get impatient thinking that they have to hammer the button again.

Skype and Messenger will show the display text to the user while sending the value, which is fine. DirectLine doesn't, though - you see nothing until the bot replies.

ImBack of course shows the 'ugly' '03 D 27913' value in the chat feed.

I'd be happy with just a button saying 'select', and the same 'select' appearing in the chat feed, and '03 D 27913' going through somehow under the hood - across all three channels, DirectLine, Skype and Messenger.

Am I missing an obvious solution, or is there a complex one involving channel data?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a consistent answer yet, here's my current hacky solution at the moment should anyone have an interest:

In bot code, use PostBack for all channels except DirectLine, which should use ImBack.

Decide yourself on an easy way to identify an 'ugly value' that you want to hide, e.g. my car reg numbers are preceded by a star-pipe, e.g. *|03 D 27913

On Skype/Messenger, PostBack will show 'select' and send the id correctly under the hood.

On DirectLine/your web chat page, you'll see the 'ugly id' in the ImBacks. So use a `setInterval` in your JS to select on `.wc-message-from-me`  and inspect its child spans for IDs, e.g. 'starts with *|', and replace with 'select' instead.

I use an interval of 100ms and it works well. As solution elegance goes, it's unpleasant, but acceptable. Performance testing: avg 0.2ms call cost. Profiler results: 0.518s of scripting in a 19.6s sample, including all other scripting.

You are asking now - why not subscribe to the DirectLine connection's message event instead, i.e. `botConnection.activity$.subscribe(message => {...`? Unfortunately, this is not called at the instant the message is entered by the user - only when the bot replies, when you get two callbacks, one for the bot message and one for your user message. It's far too late by this time.

Comment: It might be slightly cleaner (i.e. no need to set an interval) to modify the webchat to function the same way as Skype and messenger for PostBacks.

Comment: I agree in principle Mark, in fact I'm using a modified WebChat clone as it is for some trivial structural styling changes. I'm not React/Redux-y enough yet to have the time to make a significant change like that though. BTW WebChat is actually functioning the most 'correctly' out of the three; Messenger & Skype are behaving like that on PostBack by accident. I believe support for 'displayText' is in the pipeline.